# Azure MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, azure

I am trying to install http://prosper202.com (self hosted script on Azure )

**Here is what i have done.**

Created a Azure Website with MySQL Database.

Configured Database login Credentials.

**Now i am getting this error**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND 202_summary_overview.click_time < AND landing_page_id=0 ' at
>   line 12

```
SELECT 202_aff_campaigns.aff_campaign_id
    , aff_campaign_name
    , aff_campaign_payout
    , aff_network_name
FROM 202_summary_overview
LEFT JOIN 202_aff_campaigns USING (aff_campaign_id)
LEFT JOIN 202_aff_networks USING (aff_network_id)
WHERE 202_aff_networks.user_id = '1'
    AND 202_aff_networks.aff_network_deleted = 0
    AND 202_aff_campaigns.aff_campaign_deleted = 0
    AND 202_summary_overview.click_time >=
    AND 202_summary_overview.click_time <
    AND landing_page_id = 0
GROUP BY aff_campaign_id
ORDER BY 202_aff_networks.aff_network_name ASC
    , 202_aff_campaigns.aff_campaign_name ASC


Warning: Division by zero in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\click\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\202-config\functions-tracking202.php on line 1048 SELECT * FROM 202_sort_keywords LEFT JOIN 202_keywords ON (202_sort_keywords.keyword_id = 202_keywords.keyword_id) WHERE 202_sort_keywords.user_id='1' ORDER BY 202_sort_keywords.sort_keyword_clicks DESC LIMIT

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

I have no clue to fix this problem.

Can i use Azure SQL in place os MySQL , without any modification in script?

Further `http://click.azurewebsites.net/tracking202/setup/aff_campaigns.php`

**Gives me these Errors**

```
INSERT INTO `202_aff_campaigns` SET`aff_network_id`='1', `user_id`='1', `aff_campaign_name`='eDates', `aff_campaign_url`='http://googl.com', `aff_campaign_url_2`='', `aff_campaign_url_3`='', `aff_campaign_url_4`='', `aff_campaign_url_5`='', `aff_campaign_rotate`='0', `aff_campaign_payout`='0.9', `aff_campaign_cloaking`='1', `aff_campaign_time`='1355885344'

Field 'aff_campaign_id_public' doesn't have a default value
```

This same script hosted here http://prosper202.com/ is working of thousands on server. But its not working on Azure MySQL.

**Some more details**

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfhPs.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have no value supplied on which the column will be compare to,

```
SELECT  ....
FROM    ....
WHERE   ....
    AND 202_aff_campaigns.aff_campaign_deleted = 0
    AND 202_summary_overview.click_time >=    // << error on this line
    AND 202_summary_overview.click_time <     // << also here
    AND landing_page_id = 0
```

Comment: But the same script listed here is working on thousands of server http://prosper.tracking202.com/apps/download/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a record into user_pref for the new user...so i just copied the first user record into second and just update the user_id accordingly.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * FROM 202_users_pref WHERE user_id = 1;
UPDATE tmp SET user_id=2 WHERE user_id = 1;
INSERT INTO 202_users_pref SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE user_id = 2;
DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Hope this helps someone